# configuring parse-server S3adaptor

Tags: json, node.js, parse-server

I'm making use of the parse-server 2.1.4 ( latest build ) and configuring a JSON file to start with PM2.  My ecosystem.json file looks like this:

```
"apps" : [{
    "name"        : "parse-server",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-server",
    "watch"       : true,
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/home/parse",
    "env": {
      "PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD_CODE_MAIN": "/home/parse/cloud/main.js",
      "PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI": “*”,
      "PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID": “*”,
      "PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY": “*”,
      "PARSE_SERVER_FILE_KEY": “*”,
      "PARSE_SERVER_JAVASCRIPT_KEY": “*”,
      "PARSE_SERVER_REST_API_KEY": “*”,
      "PARSE_SERVER_FILES_ADAPTER": “S3Adaptor”,
    }
  }]
}
```

Problem is i'm not sure how to configure the keys/bucket for the S3Adaptor through this JSON file. The previous version i managed to do it via editing the `user/bin/parse-server` directly.

Does anybody know how to enable this adaptor? I tried setting the env above but that seems to break
SRC: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Comment: Spoke to developer, seem there is no support for the env. So will have to hard code it in. Will post it once i have it working.

Comment: Were you able to get it working? I followed the instructions, but the files are not going to my S3 bucket. They look like they are stored locally on my heroku server as a text file.

Answer (score 0):

update correct your filesAdapter in index.js file. Those key and value can set up through the environment variable.

filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
    process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    {directAccess: true}
  ),